# Python multiprocessing process hangs at the end of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a python script driving me crazy.
Right now i have a infinite loop that checks a data and get into a function in a specific situation.

```
while true:
    time.sleep(1)
    peso = getPeso()
    if peso > 900:
        processo = multiprocessing.Process(target=processo_automatico)
        processo.start()
        processo.join()
        andare() #this is where it should go after the process.
```

The function works a lot of times but nondeterministically it hangs at the end of the process (literally finish and hangs there forever. How do i know this? i tried with logs).

So at the beginning I tried to terminate it with exit codes:

```
processo.join(timeout=10)
if processo.exitcode is None:
    errore_cicalino() #this is just a warning for me
    processo.kill()                        
elif processo.exitcode != 0:
    errore_cicalino()
    processo.kill()
```

but this never worked. NEVER.
So i tried without the join(). Tried with is_alive().

```
time.sleep(10)
if processo.is_alive():
    processo.terminate()
    errore_cicalino()
```

and even like this, it never entered this if.
This is driving me crazy, i accept the fact that the process could fail but, after the timeout, i should be able to terminate it and carry on with the script.

The script is running on a Raspberry Pi 4 2 GB.

Any idea?

Minimal example:

```
while True:
   time.sleep(10)
   processo = multiprocessing.Process(target=processo_automatico)
   processo.start()
   processo.join()
```

code randomly hangs at the end of the started process and cannot terminate in any way.
processo_automatico() is a function where the script get a picture from a camera and upload it in a DB thanks to another module.

```
def processo_automatico():
        now = str(datetime.now())
        now = now.replace(":", "-")
        foto = CAMERA.read_camera()
        cv2.imwrite("/var/www/html/" + now + ".png", foto)
        DB.insert("/var/www/html/" + now + ".png", peso)
```

They don't create exceptions and i already tried to add to the end of the function a log info(executed even when the code hangs)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to create a [mre]? This will make it easier to assist you.

Comment: @importrandom Is this okay?

Comment: What is `processo_automatico`?

Comment: Added it to the post. It's a complex function. I know that that isn't the problem cause i added a log info at the end of it and, even when the code hangs, that code is all executed. But still, i should be able to terminate it

Comment: If as you say, processo_automatico can't be the problem, then you could replace all of its code with a simple time delay (time.sleep(1.0)) and the problem you're describing would still occur.  Have you tried that?  That should be your minimum reproducible example.  You might try running the function without using multiprocessing and see if it terminates every time.

Comment: I already tried with the time delay and it enters the timeout and kill it. It's something between the end of the process and the next instructions that is not working fine. Don't know what and don't know how i could try tho

Comment: This is indeed a strange one.  If the program framework is working correctly when you replace the functionality with a time delay, then the problem must be with the functionality that you replaced.  Those look to me like hardware functions: a camera and some network transactions.  Do they required finalization, or closing a library or something?  Can you put in some exception handling - what if you have an uncaught exception?  Can you run processo_automatico without multiprocessing - just to try to get to the bottom of whatever is going on?

Comment: @PaulCornelius https://github.com/AndrewMarines/CEF_BERGAMO

Comment: I'll try this afternoon without multiprocessing

Comment: I looked briefly at the CAMERA code and I didn't see anything that could cause a problem.  In your original question you said you tried .join() with a timeout of ten seconds, and that it "never worked."  What happened?  Did it just hang always?

Comment: @PaulCornelius could it be the DB code? i updated it now without the try except finally cause i didn't know if the close connection could give me issues and just now moved the while(so all the process) in the main file without the multiprocessing.  1 out of 30 times it just hangs randomly and without an exception.

Comment: tried without multiprocessing and without try...except in the DB module. Still hangs at the end of the while

Comment: I'm starting to think that the problem is connected to the raspberry pi. There's no way that the script could stop working like this

Comment: I am out of suggestions.  In your place I think I would probably initialize a logging feature and dump a lot of debugging information to a file (or the console).  Something must be different about that 1 in 30 run where it fails.  I agree that the script shouldn't stop working like that, but there are lots of raspberry pi's out there and they shouldn't stop working either!

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
What was that?
Well, my focus was on the end of the process while the issue was right at the start.
See the function getPeso()? That one just gets values from the serial.
After a few hours of getting those values the raspberry py just starts to see random values and you gotta reboot to fix it.
I wasn't prepared for that. My function just became a recursive infinite function with no break.
My tip, do not use infinite cycles except if you really need to or at least think if it could get stuck somewhere and check it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).